# How to attach an image to a post through Java

Tags: posts

I am trying to create post and attach image to wordpress using XMLRPC through Java code. Creating post and pages went out fine but can't find how to attach an image. Please help.

Comment: through java or javascript?

Comment: its through java...sorry for the wrong tag

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355922/set-featured-image-for-wordpress-post-via-xml-rpc?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17791287/309599) may be of help regarding xmlrpc

Comment: Have you considered using the REST API instead? Much much easier

Comment: yeah...had did with postman and was successful... but I need to do it with java

Comment: @hwl: Thank you for the links...had gone through it but it doesn't tell how to upload an image through java

Comment: what does it mean "attach"?  do you mean upload or something else?

Comment: upload or attach the image to the post

Comment: perhaps examining [this function](https://github.com/canbican/wordpress-java/blob/master/test/net/bican/wordpress/test/MediaTest.java#L56) will help